# ovirt:create iso/nfs storage domain erro

Tags: development-environment, virtualization, fedora

I met a problem while creating

> "New Domain" iso/nfs storage,it prints "Error while executing action
>   New NFS Storage Domain: Storage domain remote path not mounted"

and  the error code is 477.

I followed the "http://wiki.ovirt.org/wiki/Troubleshooting_NFS_Storage_Issues" and find that the vdsm user can't now use mount.

> "mount: only root can do that"

the version I use:

```
oVirt Engine Version: 3.1.0-2.fc17 
oVirt Node Hypervisor 2.5.4-0.1.fc17
```

the error log:

```
2012-11-08 09:15:00,004 INFO  [org.ovirt.engine.core.bll.AutoRecoveryManager] (QuartzScheduler_Worker-77) Checking autorecoverable storage domains done
2012-11-08 09:17:28,920 WARN  [org.ovirt.engine.core.bll.GetConfigurationValueQuery] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-2) calling GetConfigurationValueQuery (StorageDomainNameSizeLimit) with null version, 
using default general for version
2012-11-08 09:17:29,333 INFO  [org.ovirt.engine.core.vdsbroker.vdsbroker.ValidateStorageServerConnectionVDSCommand] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-3) [7720b88f] START, ValidateStorageServerConnectionVDSCommand(vdsId = 12bcf124-29a4-11e2-bcba-00505680002a, storagePoolId = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, storageType = NFS, connectionList = [{ id: 6556c55d-42a4-4dcc-832c-4d8987ebe6bd, connection: 200.200.101.219:/usr/lwq/iso };]), log id: 52777a80
2012-11-08 09:17:29,388 INFO  [org.ovirt.engine.core.vdsbroker.vdsbroker.ValidateStorageServerConnectionVDSCommand] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-3) [7720b88f] FINISH, ValidateStorageServerConnectionVDSCommand, return: {6556c55d-42a4-4dcc-832c-4d8987ebe6bd=0}, log id: 52777a80
2012-11-08 09:17:29,392 INFO  [org.ovirt.engine.core.bll.storage.AddStorageServerConnectionCommand] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-3) [7720b88f] Running command: AddStorageServerConnectionCommand internal: false. Entities affected :  ID: aaa00000-0000-0000-0000-123456789aaa Type: System
2012-11-08 09:17:29,404 INFO  [org.ovirt.engine.core.vdsbroker.vdsbroker.ConnectStorageServerVDSCommand] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-3) [7720b88f] START, ConnectStorageServerVDSCommand(vdsId = 12bcf124-29a4-11e2-bcba-00505680002a, storagePoolId = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, storageType = NFS, connectionList = [{ id: 6556c55d-42a4-4dcc-832c-4d8987ebe6bd, connection: 200.200.101.219:/usr/lwq/iso };]), log id: 36cb94f
2012-11-08 09:17:29,656 INFO  [org.ovirt.engine.core.vdsbroker.vdsbroker.ConnectStorageServerVDSCommand] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-3) [7720b88f] FINISH, ConnectStorageServerVDSCommand, return: {6556c55d-42a4-4dcc-832c-4d8987ebe6bd=477}, log id: 36cb94f
2012-11-08 09:17:29,658 ERROR [org.ovirt.engine.core.bll.storage.NFSStorageHelper] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-3) [7720b88f] The connection with details 200.200.101.219:/usr/lwq/iso failed because of
 error code 477 and error message is: 477
2012-11-08 09:17:29,717 INFO  [org.ovirt.engine.core.bll.storage.AddNFSStorageDomainCommand] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-11) [1661aa36] Running command: AddNFSStorageDomainCommand internal: false. En
tities affected :  ID: aaa00000-0000-0000-0000-123456789aaa Type: System
2012-11-08 09:17:29,740 INFO  [org.ovirt.engine.core.vdsbroker.vdsbroker.CreateStorageDomainVDSCommand] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-11) [1661aa36] START, CreateStorageDomainVDSCommand(vdsId = 12bcf12
4-29a4-11e2-bcba-00505680002a, storageDomain=org.ovirt.engine.core.common.businessentities.storage_domain_static@4a900545, args=200.200.101.219:/usr/lwq/iso), log id: 50b803a0
2012-11-08 09:17:35,233 ERROR [org.ovirt.engine.core.vdsbroker.vdsbroker.BrokerCommandBase] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-11) [1661aa36] Failed in CreateStorageDomainVDS method
2012-11-08 09:17:35,234 ERROR [org.ovirt.engine.core.vdsbroker.vdsbroker.BrokerCommandBase] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-11) [1661aa36] Error code StorageDomainFSNotMounted and error message VDSGeneri
cException: VDSErrorException: Failed to CreateStorageDomainVDS, error = Storage domain remote path not mounted: ('/rhev/data-center/mnt/200.200.101.219:_usr_lwq_iso',)
2012-11-08 09:17:35,260 INFO  [org.ovirt.engine.core.vdsbroker.vdsbroker.BrokerCommandBase] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-11) [1661aa36] Command org.ovirt.engine.core.vdsbroker.vdsbroker.CreateStorageD
omainVDSCommand return value
```

Comment: This is probably [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know VDSM does sudo to run privileged commands, but still that mount error is strange. Can you send share the vdsm log?

Also, you may get more attention on the engine-users or vdsm mailing lists.